# Regarding String functionality

Tags: string

I was developing the below class..

```
public class Test1 
{
    public void method(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("Object Verion");
    }   
    public void method(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("String Version");
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test1 question = new Test1();
        //question.method(question);

        question.method(null);
    }

}
```

Now upon executing it invokes string version as output So please advise here string is treated as null and what should we pass to invoke the object version.Thanks in advance

Comment: Got the  object version too..!! by uncommenting //question.method(question);

Comment: so, is this question resolved?

Comment: @YosepKim..yeah buddy..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other things being equal, **the most-specific method will be called.** From [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/):

> #### [15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
> method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
> descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
> language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
> another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
> on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

`question.method(null)` *could* mean either the `String` or `Object` overload, but since `String` is more specific (narrower) than `Object`, the `String` overload is the method that is called.